# hadoop command stop working when used in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop

I have used `-mv` (move) command in my shell script. It was running successfully when tested. After some runs it fails which results in script failure.

Why does this happen? I'm not getting answer to it.

```
hadoop fs -mv /user/abc/"$CURRENT_DATE" /user/xyz/Itr2Run"$run_index"
```

using Bourne shell to run script `#!/bin/sh.`

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` is not bourne shell!! BTW what was the error you encountered..

Comment: where are CURRENT_DATE and run_index set?

Comment: these are the variables i have declared in shell script. Command not found  is printed on console and whole script ran without exiting.

Comment: Check if the hadoop path is available when you are running the script. You can simply try `hadoop version` in the script to debug.